# If I make ghusl and then I have a wet dream do I make ghusl agian

Tags: fiqh, women

As-Salam-u-Alaikum 
Okay so I made ghusl at night and then I went to sleep and then I think I had a wet and I woke up wet as well but I wasn’t sure if I had to do ghusl or not so I did my Wudu and prayed . My question I’d that should’ve I made ghusl or not and did my prayer account even though I had doubts in it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a wet dream you become ritually unclean and need to do ghusl to regain purity. Having done any ghusl *before* it will not count. Salah is not valid in a state of uncleanliness, you should redo the prayer.